# Google Chrome prevents me from pulling HTML off my DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to get HTML out of my Database and put it inside a `<div></div>` like this:

`<div>stuff from DB</div>`

Example:

If `col_val = '<h1>Welcome!</h1>'` It should be:

## Welcome

Which is: `<div><h1>Welcome</h1></div>`,

But instead it shows me the `<h1>Welcome</h1>` as text..

*Note: This works on Firefox just fine but for some reason in chrome it shows text*

Anyone knows why?

---

Edit:

I'm taking the HTML using AJAX (sending a query to a php page which gives me the HTML code. Again, This works on Firefox but not on Chrome.

---

Edit 2:
Code ex:
`$.get( "htmlcon.php?id=1", function( data ) {
  $( "#div1" ).html( data );
  alert( "done" );
});`

`htmlcon.php?id=1` returns `<h1>Welcome</h1>`

Comment: You haven't provided any details of your problem at all. Are you connecting to a database directly from a client or is it going through a server first?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Edited

Comment: As Andrew asked, can you show your javascript code that requests the html and also places the returned html into the page?

Comment: You shouldn't store HTML in your database, anyways.

Comment: @moonwave99 Let's first solve his issue and then give him advice on the best way to solve his problem. We don't have enough information about his project to make a claim like that.

Comment: First inspect the element and see if div is there.Add some border color to div.

Comment: Okay, I guess, the jquery function you using to `append/replace` HTML is culprit.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Added code example

Comment: @KishorPawar When I inspect the element in Chrome it looks like [THIS](http://image.prntscr.com/image/f531645b66f94ba5af8bc6bd92224b75.png) and in Firefox it looks like [THIS](http://image.prntscr.com/image/15e9599b67e24aeb8fce9c974200a4c4.png)

Comment: @badprogrammerqq Not too sure exactly, perhaps the server isn't setting the correct content type.. either way in the jquery ajax options you should be able to set the content type you are expecting by setting `dataType: 'html'`.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Still the same :\

Comment: Look at the request and response headers, are the Content-Type headers text or html?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Didn't try that, I'll try now and update!

Answer (score 0):

`.html()`  method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided.

this is what I found in [API doc](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

I would suggest try using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element
>   in the set of matched elements